# Getting an error when running "flutter pub get"

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have cloned a Repo of a Flutter project from my developer who has the App working perfectly on his machine, and opened the project in VS Code. I did flutter clean, then flutter pub get, and am getting an error as shown below. AFAIK when I clone the repo, I should get his exact files, so I don't understand how I am getting this error, but he does not? Does anyone know how to fix this? TIA for any and all help.

```
Because every version of charts_flutter from git depends on logging ^1.0.2 and signalr_client >=0.1.3 depends on logging ^0.11.3+2, charts_flutter from git is incompatible with signalr_client >=0.1.3.
So, because app1 depends on both signalr_client ^0.1.6 and charts_flutter from git, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in App1...                              
pub get failed (1; So, because app1 depends on both signalr_client ^0.1.6 and charts_flutter from git, version solving failed.)
```

Comment: It could be possible he's using an older version of Flutter that doesn't surface this version solving issue. See this [Pratik Butani Medium post](https://pratikbutani.medium.com/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b).

Answer (score 0):

The reason is simple

The both two packages depends on one common package

Signalr_client & Charts Flutter packages needs the logging package as a dependency.

See the pubspec file

https://github.com/soernt/signalr_client/blob/master/pubspec.yaml
https://github.com/google/charts/blob/master/charts_flutter/pubspec.yaml
[image]

[image]

But the versions are different for that.

Solution:

1. Try to remove the logger package from the pub_cache folder.
2. remote any one package signalr_client or charts_flutter.
3. use syncfusion_charts instead of charts_flutter
4. Try to update the flutter packages